# Geting product attributes in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get my product attributes `title` `price` and `id` only in my controller in order to use them in my cart::add attributes.

here is my function on adding product to my cart `currently`

```
public function addingItem($id)
    {
      $product = Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'attributes' => array(),
      ));
      Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

and this is what I've done to it, obviously my code didn't work that's why i'm asking here! :)

```
public function addingItem($id)
    {
      $product = Product::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
//newly added
      foreach($product->suboptions as $subs) {
        $title = $subs->title;
        $price = $subs->price;
      }

      $customAttributes = [
            'attr' => [
                'label' => $subs->title,
                'price' => $subs->price,
            ]
        ];

      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'attributes' => array($customAttributes), //and added here
      ));
      Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## What my point is of doing this?

this is my package default sample:

```
Cart::add(array(
  array(
      'id' => 456,
      'name' => 'Sample Item 1',
      'price' => 67.99,
      'quantity' => 4,
      'attributes' => array()
  ),
  array(
      'id' => 568,
      'name' => 'Sample Item 2',
      'price' => 69.25,
      'quantity' => 4,
      'attributes' => array(
        'size' => 'L',
        'color' => 'blue'
      )
  ),
));
```

As you can see i try to get attribute part of this code and for that i've made another loop in my function (which you can see it in my second code) by that I will load attributes info in my product detail and value of thos will add to my controller attributes array.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping an array in an array, is this intended?

```
 $customAttributes = [
        'attr' => [
            'label' => $subs->title,
            'price' => $subs->price,
        ]
    ];
```

and then:

```
 'attributes' => array($customAttributes), //and added here
```

Furthermore, this is overwriting the variables `$title` and `$price` each pass through the loop:

```
foreach($product->suboptions as $subs) {
    $title = $subs->title;
    $price = $subs->price;
  }
```

and then you attempt to access `$subs` outside the loop:

```
  $customAttributes = [
        'attr' => [
            'label' => $subs->title,
            'price' => $subs->price,
        ]
    ];
```

Edit:

Change

```
'attributes' => array($customAttributes), //and added here
```

to

```
'attributes' => $customAttributes, //and added here
```

and move the $customAttributes inside the loop:

```
foreach($product->suboptions as $subs) {
    $customAttributes[] = [
        'attr' => [
            'label' => $subs->title,
            'price' => $subs->price,
        ]
    ];
}
```

Notice that

```
$customAttributes = ...
```

becomes

```
$customAttributes[] = ...
```

so as to not override the $customAttributes each time.

Comment: hi, that was answer or question? because i know my code is wrong i need help to fix it.

Comment: I was noting the incorrect areas of code, see my edit for suggetions to fix it.

Comment: i get this error ` Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message`

Comment: how should i define `label` and `price` field in frontend?

Comment: The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is likely because you are using `GET` instead of `POST`.

Comment: that was correct, but something went wrong! now when i add some product it removes last one!

Comment: I'd need to see the `Cart` class interface to know how it's supposed to work. You may be overwriting the contents using `Cart::add()` but that's just a guess. Which library are you using for `Cart`?

Comment: here is package i use https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart  you can see everything you need in their documentation.

Comment: Do you have unique id's for each product?

`// NOTE:
// Please keep in mind that when adding an item on cart, the "id" should be unique as it serves as
// row identifier as well. If you provide same ID, it will assume the operation will be an update to its quantity
// to avoid cart item duplicates`

Comment: Try adding a session id to the cart for the user like `Cart::session($userId)->add(...)`

Comment: I did that bro, there is 2 issues here: 1) how do I define my field in frontend `form` (i mean what should i put in name="??") 2- currently it will get all options even if i'm not choose any! (i think it's related to no.1)